# Probability of getting two balls of the same colour

Tags: probability, combinations

Q.There are 2 red balls and 1 blue ball in a bag. 2 balls have to be drawn from a bag at the same time. Find the probability that both drawn balls are red.

**My solution**

Since I have to draw 2 balls from bag, Either I can draw both red balls or 1 red and 1 blue at time.

Total no. of possible outcomes =2

Total no. of favourable outcomes=1

P(Both balls are red)=1/2

**Book solution**

P(Both balls are red)=No.of ways to draw Two ball from two red ball/Total no. Of choosing

P=2C2/3C2=1/3

Where am  I doing wrong ?

Comment: The two (color combo) outcomes in your first solution are NOT  equally likely, so you CAN'T compute probability in that model by doing (number favorable)/(total number). To see it more vividly, draw two from $2$ Reds and $100$ blues ... three different color combos ... but obviously your chance of two reds is less than $1/3$.

Comment: What would be possible sample space ?

Comment: To get equally likely outcomes, take the sample space to be (unordered) pairs of balls, not pairs of colors. There are three equally likely pairs of balls, one of which consists of the two reds.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it differently: you take 2 balls in the following manner -pick 1 ball but don't look at it and then pick another ball without looking at it (so you have 2 balls in your hand at the same time).

Question: what is the probability that the first one is RED:

Answer: ${\frac{2}{3}}$

What is the probability that the next one is red?
Answer: ${\frac{1}{2}}$

so you have ${\frac{2}{3} * \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{3}}$

Let me throw another pointer here: what if you were told there are 100 red balls - would you also say that it's 1/2 probability because it's either 2 red or mix? I guess not. Bottom line: number of unique EVENTS vs number of possibilities are different.

Comment: What if I have to draw both at same time.

Comment: @noviceprogrammer You are drawing them at the same time (you're not looking at them).

Answer (score 0):

You can describe any selection by the identity of the *single* ball that remains in the bag.  (The two red balls are different.). Clearly, then, the answer is $1/3$.

The following are equally like scenarios:

1. leave red ball 1 in bag
2. leave red ball 2 in bag
3. leave blue ball in bag

Comment: Sorry , I didn't get your point.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is look at all the possible outcomes since it is such a small # of balls.  Let B = Blue, R1 = Red ball 1, R2 = Red ball 2.  Let's assume the balls are marked but you cannot see those marks as you draw the balls and all the balls feel the same so you cannot tell which is which.  The possible outcomes are:

B R1 (or R1 B)
B R2 (or R2 B)
R1 R2 (or R2 R1)

So either way (whether you count permutations or not), there is a 1 in 3 chance of getting both reds (R1 R2) or 2 in 6 chance (if you count permutations).